# Show 'P' instead of NULL values in PIVOT table

Tags: sql, sql-server, pivot-table

I am working on a PIVOT data and I am stuck at one point. This is my procedure:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[usp_GetLeaveReportOrg]
@startDate date,
@endDate date

AS
BEGIN
DECLARE @DynamicPivotQuery AS NVARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @ColumnName AS NVARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @leaveReport TABLE (
    BuddyId bigint,
    Name nvarchar(300),
    RoleName nvarchar(150),
    DivisionName nvarchar(200),
    LeaveTypeName nvarchar(max),
    DateFrom date,
    DateTo date
 )

 insert into @leaveReport
 select tbl_Lm.BuddyId, tbl_Bm.Name,tbl_Rm.RoleName, tbl_Dm.DivisionName,tbl_Lt.LeaveTypeName,tbl_Lm.DateFrom, tbl_Lm.DateTo from tbl_LeaveMaster as tbl_Lm 
inner join tbl_BuddyMaster as tbl_Bm on tbl_Bm.id= tbl_Lm.BuddyId inner join tbl_DivisionMaster as tbl_Dm on tbl_Dm.Id = tbl_Bm.Divisionid 
inner join tbl_LeaveType as tbl_Lt on  tbl_Lt.Id = tbl_Lm.LeaveTypeId inner join tbl_RoleMaster as tbl_Rm on tbl_Lt.Id = tbl_Rm.Id

select BuddyId,Name,  RoleName , DivisionName,DateFrom, isnull(LeaveTypeName,'P') temp into #PivotLeaveData from @leaveReport where
CAST (DateFrom as date) >= cast(@startDate as date) and 
cast(DateTo as date) <= cast(@endDate as date)
order by DateFrom  ASC 

SELECT @ColumnName =COALESCE (@ColumnName + ',[' + CONVERT(NVARCHAR, [DateFrom], 106) + ']', 
           '[' + CONVERT(NVARCHAR, [DateFrom], 106) + ']')
           FROM    (SELECT DISTINCT [DateFrom] FROM #PivotLeaveData) PV  
           ORDER BY [DateFrom]

 SET @DynamicPivotQuery = 
N'SELECT BuddyId,Name,RoleName,DivisionName, ' + @ColumnName + '
FROM #PivotLeaveData
PIVOT(Max( [LeaveTypeName]   ) 
      FOR [DateFrom] IN (' + @ColumnName + ')) AS PVTTable'

EXEC(@DynamicPivotQuery)

END
```

**PROBLEM:**

What I want is, I want to display 'P' for the **LeaveTypeName** if entry is null. That means, the employee is present at that day. When I am using isNull it showing NULL instead of P.

**WHAT I TRIED**:

- Using COALESCE function to replace the **LeaveTypeName** with P, but that doesn't work either.
- Using ISNULL, but no luck.

**EDIT:**
Here is my sample data:

```
BuddyId   Name  RoleName    DivisionName   01Jan2020     02Jan2020    ....
1          ABC  Developer    Dev              NULL      Casual Leave
2          DEF  Maintenance  Maintenance    Sick Leave   NULL
```

**WHAT I NEED:**
Replace the Nulls with 'P'

Where I am going wrong?

Comment: can you share sample data? Also, try with nullif. You might me getting ''(blank) instead of null in your LeaveTypeName

Comment: i think you are doing a lot of unnecessary things in your stored procedure. You first insert into `table variable` and then into `temp table` and finally `PIVOT`ing. You should be able to simplified all just a `PIVOT` query without `table variable` and `temp table`

Comment: @Atk, please see my edit

Comment: @RohanRao -- thanks for the question. What about creating a SQL Fiddle in sql-server here with some sample data: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18. I'm not sure how 'flexible' it is with stored procedures, but I'm sure you can boil it down to some sample data (inserted, permanently) and the query, and it should make things much easier for people to answer.

Comment: Dirty solution; put the results of your PIVOT into (yet another) temp table, select from that table using ISNULL or COALESCE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use another variable to handle null data

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[usp_GetLeaveReportOrg]
@startDate date,
@endDate date

AS
BEGIN
DECLARE @DynamicPivotQuery AS NVARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @ColumnName AS NVARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @ShowColumnName AS NVARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @leaveReport TABLE (
    BuddyId bigint,
    Name nvarchar(300),
    RoleName nvarchar(150),
    DivisionName nvarchar(200),
    LeaveTypeName nvarchar(max),
    DateFrom date,
    DateTo date
 )

 insert into @leaveReport
 select tbl_Lm.BuddyId, tbl_Bm.Name,tbl_Rm.RoleName, tbl_Dm.DivisionName,tbl_Lt.LeaveTypeName,tbl_Lm.DateFrom, tbl_Lm.DateTo from tbl_LeaveMaster as tbl_Lm 
inner join tbl_BuddyMaster as tbl_Bm on tbl_Bm.id= tbl_Lm.BuddyId inner join tbl_DivisionMaster as tbl_Dm on tbl_Dm.Id = tbl_Bm.Divisionid 
inner join tbl_LeaveType as tbl_Lt on  tbl_Lt.Id = tbl_Lm.LeaveTypeId inner join tbl_RoleMaster as tbl_Rm on tbl_Lt.Id = tbl_Rm.Id

select BuddyId,Name,  RoleName , DivisionName,DateFrom, LeaveTypeName into #PivotLeaveData from @leaveReport where
CAST (DateFrom as date) >= cast(@startDate as date) and 
cast(DateTo as date) <= cast(@endDate as date)
order by DateFrom  ASC 

SELECT @ColumnName =COALESCE (@ColumnName + ',[' + CONVERT(NVARCHAR, [DateFrom], 106) + ']', 
           '[' + CONVERT(NVARCHAR, [DateFrom], 106) + ']')
           FROM    (SELECT DISTINCT [DateFrom] FROM #PivotLeaveData) PV  
           ORDER BY [DateFrom]

SELECT @ShowColumnName=COALESCE (@ColumnName + ',ISNULL([' + CONVERT(NVARCHAR, [DateFrom], 106) + '],''P'') as '+'[' + CONVERT(NVARCHAR, [DateFrom], 106) + ']', 
           'ISNULL([' + CONVERT(NVARCHAR, [DateFrom], 106) + '],''P'') as '+'[' + CONVERT(NVARCHAR, [DateFrom], 106) + ']')
           FROM    (SELECT DISTINCT [DateFrom] FROM #PivotLeaveData) PV  
           ORDER BY [DateFrom]


 SET @DynamicPivotQuery = 
N'SELECT BuddyId,Name,RoleName,DivisionName, ' + @ShowColumnName+ '
FROM #PivotLeaveData
PIVOT(Max( [LeaveTypeName]   ) 
      FOR [DateFrom] IN (' + @ColumnName + ')) AS PVTTable'

EXEC(@DynamicPivotQuery)

END
```

Comment: Thanks, but it is giving 'Invalid column name 'LeaveTypeName'

Comment: @RohanRao check my updated answer, if it is correct then mark it as answer.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
DECLARE @ColumnNameNOTnull AS NVARCHAR(MAX)

SELECT @ColumnNameNOTnull =
            STUFF(
            (
                SELECT ', ISNULL(' + QUOTENAME([DateFrom]) + ', ''P'') AS ' + QUOTENAME([DateFrom])
                FROM (SELECT DISTINCT [DateFrom] FROM #PivotLeaveData) tempTBL
                ORDER BY [DateFrom]
                FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)')
            ,1 , 1, '')

 SET @DynamicPivotQuery = 
        N'SELECT BuddyId,Name,RoleName,DivisionName, ' + @ColumnNameNOTnull + '
        FROM #PivotLeaveData
        PIVOT(Max( [LeaveTypeName]   ) 
              FOR [DateFrom] IN (' + @ColumnName + ')) AS PVTTable'
```

Comment: Thanks, it is  saying 'Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'ORDER'.'

Comment: I have put a where clause before it, but it gives too many errors. Could you please simplify?@Zhui

Comment: @RohanRao i have update my answer, please try again.

Comment: @RohanRao error on delete the comma, updated and please try again.

Comment: still getting the same error. 'Incorrect syntax near (' . Sorry for troubling you too much.